# What does the lodash get function do?

Tags: javascript, typescript, get, lodash

I am trying to make sense of this line of code:

```
const loanPeriod: number = get(product, 'TermMonths', this.defaultTerm) / this.monthsInAYear;
```

defaultTerm and monthsInAYear are global variables.  product is an object and TermMonths is a number property of product.  I don't know why the product & 'TermMonths' is needed.  Can't you just divide the defaultTerm by monthsInAYear?

Comment: What makes you think that's a lodash method?

Comment: Seems like the first thing I would do is read the documentation from lodash....

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can find the official documentation [here](https://lodash.com/docs/4.17.15#get), with an example. Using your case, the assumption is that `product` may or may not have a property called `TermMonths`. If it does, `_.get` will retrieve the value of that property. If it does not, the default, `this.defaultTerm`, is returned.

Answer (score 0):

The _.get() method is used to get the value at path of object. If the resolved value is undefined, the defaultValue is returned in its place.

Syntax:

_.get(object, path, [defaultValue])
Parameters: This method accepts three parameters as mentioned above and described below:

object: This parameter holds the object to query.
path: This parameter holds the path of the property to get. The path will be array or string.
defaultValue: This parameter holds the value returned for undefined resolved values.
Return Value: This method returns the resolved value.

src: https://www.geeksforgeeks.org/lodash-_-get-method/

In your case it gets the term of loan if not it takes default and divides it by months in years to get the total years.

Comment: Why not just use a ternary operator with a direct reference to an object’s property? I have never understood the point of _.get()

Comment: @CharlesRobertson,  think of `const source = "users[0].profile.pictures[0].src"; get(data, source)`.